# Mapstruct is unable to resolve correct package for the Target class while mapping

Tags: java, mapstruct

I am trying to map object A to object B where object B sits in generated sources of the avro package. However, I do have a similar object name in src/main/java as well.

How should I tell Mapstruct to use the subs-classes of Object B to be picked up from same package where object B is?

For example

```
type here
//This class is source object sits in src/main/java/model
class A {
private String id;
private Name name; //this class firstName and lastName fields.
}

//this class is target object that sits in target/generated-sources/avro/*
class B {
private String id;
private Name name;
}

//this sits in target/generated-sources/avro/*
class Name {
private string firstName;
private String lastName;
}
//but I do have Class Name in src/main/java/dto as well.
```

How do I tell map struct to not use the Name package from src/main/java/dto but use it from target/generated-sources/avro/* ?

My Mapper abstract class looks like this:

Object B mapFromObjectA(ObjectA a); //here Object B comes from target/avro but the inner class is being picked up from dto package which is incorrect.

Is there a way, we can tell the target package directory to Map Struct?

Comment: declare `A#name` as a FQN (`private avro.Name name`)

Comment: Could you please provide me an example, I could understand what you mean by your comment?